# Toggle visibility between DropDownList and TextBox in the given scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, toggle

In my project, I have two `RadioButtons` called `UserTypeRadio`. With that, I have a `DropDownList` and a `TextBox`. I want to `toggle` the visibility of the `DropDownList` and the `TextBox` depending on which `RadioButton` is selected.

**RadioButton**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
        <label class="fg-labels">Type of User</label><br />
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label><input type="radio" name="UserTypeRadio" id="radioButtonEmployee" value="Employee" onclick="radioButtonEmployeeSelected()" checked class="userSelection" /> Employee</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label><input type="radio" name="UserTypeRadio" id="radioButtonOtherUser" value="OtherUser" onclick="radioButtonOtherUserSelected()" class="userSelection" /> Other User</label>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**DropDownList**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
        <div class="input-group fg-float">
            <div class="fg-line form-chose">
                <label asp-for="UserId" class="fg-labels" for="userId">User Name</label>
                <select asp-for="UserId" asp-items="ViewBag.Users" class="chosen disabledropdowncntrl" data-placeholder="Choose a User" name="userId" id="dropDownUserNames">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TextBox**

```
<div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
    <div class="input-group fg-float">
        <div class="fg-line">
            <label asp-for="OtherUser" class="fg-label" for="otherUser">Other User</label>
            <input asp-for="OtherUser" class="form-control" id="textBoxOtherUser" name="otherUser" hidden />
            <span asp-validation-for="OtherUser" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$('.userSelection').on('change', function () {
    //alert($(this).val());
    //if ($(this).val() === "Employee") {
        $("#textBoxOtherUser").toggle();
        $("#dropDownUserNames").toggle();
    //}
});
```

I am trying to hide `TextBoxOtherUser` when `Employee` is selected from the `RadioButton`, and I am trying to hide `DropDownUserNames` when I click `Other User` option from the `RadioButton`.

The `toggle()` is performing as per expectation. However, on performing `Inspect Element` from the Browser, when `Other User` is selected from the `RadioButton`, I see that the `DropDownList` is not getting disbled. In fact, I see that when the `Employee` is not selected, `style="display: inline-block;"` is present in the code. On the other hand, when the `Employee` is selected, `style="display: none;"` is shown. In other words, on selecting `Employee` displays the `DropDownList` in the required UI. But when `Employee` is not selected, instead of getting disabled, the `DropDownList` is shown in the plain old block format.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using `data` attribute you can do this .. add `data-user` for employee and otheruser radio inputs and add `data-show` to the related select/textbox and you can then use the next code

```js
$('[name="UserTypeRadio"]').on('change' , function(){
  var Thisvalue = $(this).attr('data-user');
  $('[data-show]').hide().filter('[data-show="'+Thisvalue+'"]').show();
}).filter(':checked').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
        <label class="fg-labels">Type of User</label><br />
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label><input type="radio" name="UserTypeRadio" id="radioButtonEmployee" value="Employee" checked class="userSelection" data-user="employee"/> Employee</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label><input type="radio" name="UserTypeRadio" id="radioButtonOtherUser" value="OtherUser" class="userSelection" data-user="otheruser"/> Other User</label>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
        <div class="input-group fg-float">
            <div class="fg-line form-chose">
                <label asp-for="UserId" class="fg-labels" for="userId">User Name</label>
                <select asp-for="UserId" asp-items="ViewBag.Users" class="chosen disabledropdowncntrl" data-placeholder="Choose a User" name="userId" id="dropDownUserNames" data-show="employee">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
    <div class="input-group fg-float">
        <div class="fg-line">
            <label asp-for="OtherUser" class="fg-label" for="otherUser">Other User</label>
            <input asp-for="OtherUser" class="form-control" id="textBoxOtherUser" name="otherUser" data-show="otheruser" />
            <span asp-validation-for="OtherUser" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** if you include your js code before including jquery you'll need to wrap your js code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ // code here })`

Finally if you need to hide the whole `row` you can simply **cut**/paste the `data-show` attribute to the parent instead of select or textbox

```js
$('[name="UserTypeRadio"]').on('change' , function(){
  var Thisvalue = $(this).attr('data-user');
  $('[data-show]').hide().filter('[data-show="'+Thisvalue+'"]').show();
}).filter(':checked').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
        <label class="fg-labels">Type of User</label><br />
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label><input type="radio" name="UserTypeRadio" id="radioButtonEmployee" value="Employee" checked class="userSelection" data-user="employee"/> Employee</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label><input type="radio" name="UserTypeRadio" id="radioButtonOtherUser" value="OtherUser" class="userSelection" data-user="otheruser"/> Other User</label>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20" data-show="employee">
        <div class="input-group fg-float">
            <div class="fg-line form-chose">
                <label asp-for="UserId" class="fg-labels" for="userId">User Name</label>
                <select asp-for="UserId" asp-items="ViewBag.Users" class="chosen disabledropdowncntrl" data-placeholder="Choose a User" name="userId" id="dropDownUserNames">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20" data-show="otheruser">
    <div class="input-group fg-float">
        <div class="fg-line">
            <label asp-for="OtherUser" class="fg-label" for="otherUser">Other User</label>
            <input asp-for="OtherUser" class="form-control" id="textBoxOtherUser" name="otherUser" />
            <span asp-validation-for="OtherUser" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

by adding `.filter(':checked').change();` at the end this mean run the change event for the checked radio on load